# How to pass arguments to custom actions(.exe)

Tags: windows-installer, installation, custom-action

I am making a installer file using Visual studio installer project. I need to pass the user input value at install stage to a custom action(exe file) at commit stage.

I created a custom action(dll file) for install stage, to get the user input. And created custom action(exe file) for commit stage. Only thing missing is Arguments for the custom action(exe file).

How do I pass the value as arguments to custom action(exe) at commit stage?

Comment: Could you write the value to disk or to a registry key / value and then do the rest on application launch? Or are you writing to a locked-down location? (per-machine).

Answer (score 0):

Your custom action dll can set a property value, then you can pass this property as a command line parameter to your exe custom action. Just be aware about [specifics of deferred custom actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions)